A study with a time varying covariate (survival)
We are conducting a study where patients are regularly tested for cancer recurrence. Check-ups are scheduled every four months (T0, T4, T8, T12, T16, T20).
The following data likely has the appropriate structure for employing survival analysis in a discrete-time format. Please let me know if this is incorrect.
ID     TIME   EVENT   GENDER    
1      T0        0      M       
1      T4        0      M        
1      T8        0      M        
1      T12       1      M       
2      T0        0      F         
2      T4        1      F         
3      T0        0      M     
3      T4        0      M       
3      T8        1      M       
4      T0        0      F     
4      T4        1      F 

Now we need to add a time-varying covariate to the model, which is smoking.
Patients were asked about their smoking habits at each scheduled appointment.
Now, I am wondering if the following data structure is appropriate when there is a dependent covariate in the model. Additionally, can the following function be employed: glm(event ~ Time + Gender + smoke, family = binomial(link = cloglog))?
 ID     TIME   EVENT   GENDER   SMOKE   
  1      T0        0      M        0    
  1      T4        0      M        1       
  1      T8        0      M        1        
  1      T12       1      M        1       
  2      T0        0      F        0        
  2      T4        1      F        1       
  3      T0        0      M        0     
  3      T4        0      M        0       
  3      T8        1      M        0     
  4      T0        0      F        0    
  4      T4        0      F        0 
       

The second question is: Can we still use the above formula when the relative timing of covariate changes and event time intervals are not the same? If not, how can we create a dataset with the appropriate structure, and which statistical model should be used?

I want to add the keyword "discrete-time survival model"

The overall data structure seems to be correct: for each individual, one line for each time interval during which the individual is at risk, including the covariate values in place during the interval and whether the interval ended with an event.
With respect to the time-varying covariate, you need to make sure that the value is that at the beginning of the corresponding time interval. See the end of this answer and its link to a pertinent reference (Tutz and Schmid, Section 3.5).
That has implications for your modeling if you don't have recurrence information at the same time as there's a change in covariate values; you might already have had the recurrence event before the covariate value changed. The best way to proceed is to use the original covariate value until the next evaluation of recurrence, then update the covariate value for the following recurrence-evaluation time interval.
For example: Consider ID 2 above. I assume that the 4 data rows show your observations at each of those time points; that is, no SMOKE observed at T0, but both SMOKE and an event observed at T4.
For SMOKE to be a predictor of the event, you need to make sure that the value of SMOkE used for any observed event time is what was in place at the start of the time interval leading up to the event (or lack of event). Otherwise, it's possible that the event is "predicting" the value of SMOKE rather than the other way around. For ID 2 that means using SMOKE = 0 for the event at T4, because that was the value at the start of the T0-T4 time interval. That's also true for all time intervals that end without an event.
In general, when data are grouped into discrete time intervals for evaluating an event (or lack thereof), at each event-observation time you need to use the covariate value at the previous observation time. That's your best estimate of the covariate value at the start of the time interval during which the event might have happened.
If your data display represents the observations at each of those time points, then you need to move each of the SMOKE values to the following row before you run glm() (discarding the very last SMOKE for each individual, as it isn't the value at the start of any time interval of interest). That might seem to leave no covariate values for T0 but that's OK: presumably there are no events at T0 or, if there are, they wouldn't be informative for the survival analysis (which typically starts at 100survival).
The above is true for any time-varying covariate in a discrete-time model that is based on grouped data over time intervals. I'd be very skeptical, however, that changes in current smoking behavior are strongly associated with the risk of cancer recurrence. In the types of cancer I study, it's long-term smoking behavior that matters: things like pack-years of cigarette use over a lifetime or whether there has been any smoking in the past 10 or 15 years.

Thanks for the advice. Well, I did not fully comprehend your comment on the covariate time interval (“the best way to proceed is to use the original covariate value until the next evaluation of recurrence, then update the covariate value for the following recurrence-evaluation time interval”). Could you please explain it by providing an example?

In the above example, suppose that smoking = 1 is the level of our interest and Timing of smoking=1 differed between subjects. For ID = 1, the timing when smoking = 1 happened  was two intervals before the event = 1. For ID = 2, the time when smoking = 1 happened was at the time of event = 1. For ID = 3, the event happened at T8, although the status of smoking is the same (smoking = 0). I would be very thankful if you could explain your point on the covariate time interval based on this example.

@marco I added an example for ID 2 and further discussion. If you want SMOKE to be a predictor of the event, then you have to be sure that the SMOKE value was in place prior to the event. If you observe both an event and a change in SMOKE at the same time, you can't know which happened first. For each time interval during which an event might occur, you need to use the time-varying covariate value that was in place at the start of the time interval. If I understand your data structure correctly, that would be the value of SMOKE at the previous observation time.

@ EdM, Thank you so much for the help. When working with time-dependent covariates, the intervals are usually ((a(t-1), a(t)]). However, in discrete time intervals, the time-dependent covariates are ([(a(t-1), a(t))). Could you explain the reason for this difference?

@marco with time-dependent covariates in a continuous-time Cox model, if someone has the event you know that the event occurred exactly at the end point of the interval. You need to know the covariate value in place at that time, so a right-closed interval is correct for both the covariates and the event. In a discrete-time (interval-censored) model all you know is that the event occurred some time during that interval. To avoid the problem of a "predictor" change being caused by the event, you need to use covariate values in place at the start of the time interval, before the event.

@
EdM, thanks so much for the clear answer. Another question is it seems the following function from Survival package in R can be used for a discrete time (with time varying covariate) : coxph((Surv(fgstart, fgstop)~ covariate, data=, ties="exact)). Here also we need to consider the covariate values at the start of the time interval?

@marco what matters is whether or not you know the actual time of the event. The ties="exact" argument works if the event time is known precisely. That's not the case when events are discovered retrospectively at widely spaced intervals, as in your example. In practice, a Cox model might be used for the time of observing a recurrence with ties="exact", but then you have to be very careful that any time-varying covariates are coded in a way that they truly represent predictors of the event rather than results of the event.

@marco this answer to a similar question shows the problem with using the last observed covariate value as a "predictor" of an event when you have interval-censored/grouped event times; see the J. Neurooncol paper link with an unrealistically high hazard ratio due to that. In general, code the time-varying covariate so that it represents the value in place at the event time. If you know the event time then the usual counting-process data format is OK. If you only know a range containing the time, you need to proceed very carefully.

thank you so much again for your valuable time. In the survival package, it is mentioned that the “exact partial likelihood” is equivalent to a conditional logistic model and is appropriate when the times are a small set of discrete values. My understanding was that when ties = exact, we can run the discrete time Cox model, which is equivalent to running glm with cloglog. Based on your last comment, does this mean my understanding was incorrect?

@marco a "conditional logistic model" is not the same thing as a discrete-time model with cloglog link or as a Cox model solved with "exact partial likelihood." This answer explains the differences. Confusion occurs in part because code for fitting Cox models can be repurposed to fitting conditional logistic models. Also, see the distinction between "intrinsically discrete" measurements and "grouped" data (like yours) in survival models, explained about half-way down in this answer.

great, i got it, thanks so much for your time.
